# Ошибка при поиске максимального значения в массиве

Tags: java

Всем, привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, где я допустил ошибку:

**Исходный код:**

```
package ru;

import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        out.println("Заполните массив значениями!");
        //  Создадим массив значений
            int[] arrNum = new int[4];

                for(int i = 0; i <= arrNum.length - 1; i++)
                {
                    out.printf("Введите m[%d]: ", i + 1);
                        arrNum[i] = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
                }

        //  Найдем максимальное значение
            int max = arrNum[1];

                for(int i = 1; i <= arrNum.length; i++)
                {
                    if(arrNum[i] > max) // 39 строка...
                    {
                        max = arrNum[i];
                    }
                }
                    out.printf("Максимальное число в массиве: %g", max);

    }
}
```

---

> **Ошибка:**
>
> `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:  4 at ru.Main.main(Main.java:39)`

---

> **39 строка:**
>
> `if(arrNum[i] > max)`

Comment: в строке 

     for(int i = 1; i <= arrNum.length; i++)

Comment: @Артёмыч ну классика жанра же **i <= arrNum.length**. Стыдно должно быть такие ошибки допускать

Comment: условие напишите так

    i < arrNum.length

или так

    i <= arrNum.length -1

Но первый вариант лучше.

Comment: @Артёмыч пожалуйста, без мата. Мы же с вами не в привокзальной рюмочной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        out.println("Заполните массив значениями!");
        //  Создадим массив значений
        int[] arrNum = new int[4];

        for(int i = 0; i < arrNum.length; i++)
        {
            out.printf("Введите m[%d]: ", i);
            arrNum[i] = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        }

        //  Найдем максимальное значение
        int max = arrNum[0];

        for(int i = 0; i < arrNum.length; i++)
        {
            if(arrNum[i] > max)
            {
                max = arrNum[i];
            }
        }
        out.printf("Максимальное число в массиве: %d", max);

    }
}
```

Comment: я думаю, что автор вопроса разобрался уже и Ваш ответ не несет дополнительной информации.